# Event Tracking UA + Upgrading to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I've got a website where every button has an onclick parameter based [on this article]https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events. This works fine with universal analytics. But I wonder if it also works with Google Tag Manager without any adjustments. Am I fine or do I need to change code on site to get this? If I do need to change, where should I start, couldn't find any resources

Answer (score 0):

If you use GTM for event tracking, you would need to remove event tracking code on your site because this will result in double-tracking and inflated analytics data. What you can do is to tag everything you want tagged in GTM, but DO NOT publish your container and tags just yet - just work in debug mode so that you can see if/when your tags are firing. Then once everything is working in GTM debug mode, you can then remove your event tracking code and publish your container. Alternatively, if you wanted to just leave the event tracking code in your site and use GTM concurrently, then you would have to make sure you don't tag those events that are already being tracked, but really this isn't ideal and defeats the purpose of GTM.

Comment: So using ga('send', 'event) in the HTML will work along with GTM? Cause at the moment I dont want to change the source code

Comment: No, if you want to still send an event but using GTM, you will need to use the methods of GTM to do that (ie. creating a tag to fire, using some sort of listener, and setting up a rule for that tag). There are situations where you could use the ga('send','event,...) code in GTM, but that would be through custom HTML/JS, but generally speaking, all ga('send'...) method calls should be removed from the site and replaced with the equivalent in GTM.

Comment: You can set the tracker name to t0 and your old ga('send', 'event', ...) code should work.  t0 is the default tracker name that the "normal" universal analytics code would create anyway.  Use the debug analytics to verify.